# Cant find variable buffer

Tags: react-native, ethereum

I'm trying to create a buffer object in my react native project, I received an error which is "Can't find buffer variable".

I have imported the './shim.js' into the index.js file. Anyone please advise.

My project is running on react native version 0.55.4

```
 sendERCTokenWithRawTransaction(){
    var count = web3.eth.getTransactionCount(fromAddress, (error, nounce) => {
      console.log('This is the nouce'+ web3.toHex(nounce))
      var data = _myContract.transfer.getData(toAddress, 10000).encodeABI();
      var gasPrice = 100;
      var gasLimit = 8000000;

      var rawTransaction = {
        "from": fromAddress,
        "nonce": web3.toHex(nounce),
        "gasPrice": web3.toHex(gasPrice),
        "gasLimit": web3.toHex(gasLimit),
        "to": toAddress,
        "value":'0x00',
        "data": data,
        "chainId": '0x03'
      };

        var privKey = new Buffer('key', 'hex');
        var tx = new Tx(rawTransaction);

        tx.sign(privKey);
        var serializedTx = tx.serialize();
       console.log('RawTransaction :' + '0x' + serializedTx.toString('hex'))
       web3.eth.sendRawTransaction('0x' + serializedTx.toString('hex'), function(err, hash) {
        if (!err)
            console.log(hash);
        else
            console.log(err);
      });
    })
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it by commented the last line of the code in shim.js

```
// If using the crypto shim, uncomment the following line to ensure
// crypto is loaded first, so it can populate global.crypto
//require('crypto')
```